# Ruby koans: Baffled by koan 268

Tags: ruby, proxy

I've 'solved' Ruby koan 268, but it doesn't make sense to me. The project is using a Proxy object (I guess as a kind of adaptor?) to 'impersonate' a Television class.
Here's how my Proxy class ended up:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    # ADD MORE CODE HERE
    attr_accessor :messages
    @messages = []
  end

  # WRITE CODE HERE
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if @object.respond_to?(method_name)
      @messages.push(method_name)
      @object.send(method_name, *args)
    end
  end

  def messages 
    @messages
  end
end
```

Later, a Proxy Television is declared like this:

```
tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)    
tv.power
tv.channel = 10
assert_equal [:power, :channel=], tv.messages
```

My question is, why did I have to add the messages method to Proxy, when I've defined attr_accessor :messages earlier? Without the last method, the koan doesn't 'pass'. (tv.messages returns nil).

I'd really like to UNDERSTAND this as it looks to me like I'm repeating myself by defining access-to-@messages through attr_accessor AND the messages method. If attr_accessor doesn't get me access to @messages, what's the point of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code on ruby 2.1.5p273:

```
class A
  def initialize
    attr_accessor :m
  end

  def a(i)
    @m = i
  end
end

a = A.new
```

And that throws an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `attr_accessor' for #<A:0x007f8313022220>
  from (irb):3:in `initialize'
```

The problem is that `attr_accessor` is a class method, not an instance method. So, you can't call it from inside the `initialize` method. You have to put it outside, within the class body. Then it will properly setup the accessor and it'll work as you expected in the first place:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :m

  def a(i)
    @m = i
  end
end

a = A.new
a.a 'hey'
a.m # => "hey"
```

Answer (score 0):

This definition of `method_missing` covers up errors: any call to a non existant method just returns nil instead of raising NameError.

In particular your call to `attr_accessor` doesn't do anything because `attr_accessor` is not an instance method, so `method_missing` is called and swallows your mistake, so your definition of `messages` is needed to be able to get the value of `@messages`. If you call `attr_accessor` outside of the `initialize` method, then the definition of `messages` would indeed be redundant.

If you omit your `messages` method then `proxy.messages` ends up just calling `method_missing` and (unless tv had such a method) returns nil.